# Not able to install pyaudio on windows. Getting below error

Tags: python, pip, pyaudio

```
src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: **Cannot open include file: 'portaudio.h': No such file or directory**
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

----------------------------------------
Failed building wheel for pyaudio
Running setup.py clean for pyaudio
Failed to build pyaudio
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
```

Comment: How are you installing pyaudio? From source? Using pip?

Comment: Yes, we need to know how you're trying to install this. If you aren't, give it a try using: `pip install pyaudio`. Or, here's a pre-built package that you can try: http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/packages/pyaudio-0.2.8.py27.exe

Comment: Yes, using pip i'm trying to install.

Comment: using this command:====>  pip install pyaudio